# Play framework - Statis resources refresh takes time

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using activator ui. 
During the development, it is taking lot of time because even for a simple CSS or HTML change it takes lot of time to refresh. Is there any live preview option or plugin available for play framework 2.5? I aming using play 2.5.7

Comment: What is taking a long time exactly?

Comment: page refresh, to see the CSS or HTML changes.

Comment: Rather than using `activator ui` try `activator run` and access your project in the browser `http://localhost:9000/`. That will likely be quicker. You can also use `activator ~run` which polls your project for changes and causes recompilation automatically each time you make a change.  This is only for development of course but means less waiting around when you want to see the results in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, `activator ui` executes task on file change. When you make a change, it executes not only your changes, but also whole code.

Once you run the play framework(go to your project folder and type `activator run` or `play run` depends on play framework version), all you need to do is to refresh your browser. Since Play framework has hot-code feature which allows you live preview by refreshing your browser. So when you make a change, it'll response quicker with this.